# Receiving single email alert in visual flow instead of two?

Tags: email, visual-workflow, email-alert

I have created two decisions in visual flow and attached email alert for each. Here i am receiving only only mail alert even it is satisfying both the conditions.

check = airline then email alert1
check = Travel  then email alert2

Comment: Only first decision, which is being evaluated to true, is executed

Comment: What if i want to send it to multiples?

Comment: there are couple of ways to resolve that. Like make an outcome to send two emails, or make two blocks with independent decisions, or make a loops with flag variables, and recalculation of same step couple of times. Personally I like second approach

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/5eTnQ example of case 2